# how to set time interval in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm working on a project and I need to associate data, where the precision of times is given in seconds. But the times are not exact, I wanted to associate them with a time interval. How can I do this?

I tried the select values ​​to put this time interval, and I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Formula step, create a new column with the following function: NOW()[image]